# Restricting access to Placeholder CustomData

Tags: placeholders

I'd like to override Placeholder method `@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("keyName")`.

I want to achieve special behaviour to update CustomData (Editable checkbox in Placeholder item) value.

Eventhough Placeholder item sets editable as true, specific users would not be able to edit Custom Data.

Here is my code, but doesn't work.

```
public class CustomPlaceholder : SitecoreHelper
{
    public CustomPlaceholder(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        : base(htmlHelper)
    {}

    public override HtmlString Placeholder(string placeholderName)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(placeholderName, "placeholderName");
        using (Sitecore.Mvc.Common.ContextService.Get().Push(this.HtmlHelper.ViewContext))
        {
            var stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            var args = new Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.RenderPlaceholderArgs(placeholderName, stringWriter, this.CurrentRendering);

            //if (user belongs to LimitedContent role) {
            //    args.CustomData["editable"] = false;
            //} else {
            //    args.CustomData["editable"] = true;
            //}

            return new HtmlString(stringWriter.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about how you could do this with permissions?  I'm not in front of my computer right now so I can't test this but if you created a role that broke inheritance on the Placeholder item, placed all your users in this role, then, gave other roles explicit permissions on the Placeholder item, would this not accomplish what you are trying to do with code?

Comment: I did, but the behavior is different. For example, if you deny READ access in specific role, they still can add new control in the empty placeholder. If you set Editable as False, the user can't delete the control in the placeholder and they also can't add another control in the same placeholder. The updating permission could be easiest way, but not what I want to do.

Comment: What Sitecore version are you on?

Comment: It is v8.0 rev update6